# Spring Boot modifying example project - Error: Could not find or load main class hello.Application

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I imported on of the Spring Boot getting started projects,
gs-rest-service-complete and looked over it, ran it and got the
general idea how I could start things.  So needless to say, I started
to modify that project in order to get my own set of web services
started.  Originally there was an Application class in the hello
package annotated with the @SpringBootApplication and had a main
method which did a SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args) to
get it running.  Obviously I was going to use the 'hello' package, so
I deleted all that and made my own package hierarchy something on the
order of com.mycompany.product.  In that package I made an
Application.class with the same guts (but corresponding to this
package) and a controller in a subpackage of that.

When trying to start the spring boot app, i get this error in the console now:

Error: Could not find or load main class hello.Application

I have no idea what's telling it to look for that specific class in
that specific package.  There's no reference to that stuff in my
project anymore.  (running in STS).

What controls this?  What do I do?  I had assumed having only class in
the project at the top of a package layout with the
@SpringBootApplication would get everything moving 'just right'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that... The Boot Dashboard is actually a bunch of launch configurations for run or debug.

I selected my app there and realized when right clicking on it there was an option called "Open Config" which brought me to the "Debug Configurations" dialog.  And there was my answer... in the "Main type" field, it said "hello.Application".  That's where you set or change it.

I changed that to my "com.mycompany.product.Application" and the app started up as hoped!

Comment: So, if I was only running this from command-line, I probably wouldn't have hit this.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to get started with a spring boot application is to use the [initializr](https://start.spring.io/)

Click on the 'Switch to full version', fill in the details of your application and select the spring-boot starter packages you want to include. You can look in the pom.xml of the demo project you were using as a tutorial to figure out which ones you need. Then you just click the generate project button and import it into eclipse. Inside eclipse go file -> import -> Maven -> Existing maven projects. Then point to where you unzipped the file you downloaded from spring initializr and it will import your project into Eclipse.